# URL decode with R for RFC1738 (PHP default)

Tags: r, urlencode, rfc3986, rfc1738, httpuv

I need to decode **with R** strings that are URL encoded using RFC 1738.

These strings are coming from PHP requests and encoded with the PHP function `http_build_query` which [uses RFC1738 by default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

For example, `Hello, World!` becomes `Hello%2C+world%21`.

You can easily [try it online](http://www.writephponline.com/) with the following PHP code:

```php
$data = array(
    'text' => 'Hello, world!'
);

echo http_build_query($data, '', '&');
```

Unfortunately, R base URL encoding [uses RFC 3986](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.0/topics/URLencode), which is different!

```r
utils::URLdecode("Hello%2C+world%21")
# "Hello,+world!"

# I was hoping httpuv would have an option for RFC 1738 but it doesn't!
httpuv::decodeURIComponent("Hello%2C+world%21")
# "Hello,+world!"
```

I want to get `"Hello, world!"` back! How can I do that with R?

> I am happy to just replace `+` signs with spaces but, if this is your answer, please justify why this is correct. My research so far did not indicate that RFC 1738 is *exactly* RFC 3986 with plus signs and I don't want weird edge cases...

Comment: This issue might be unrelated to RFC1738 but due to the *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* media type, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20. R's `utils::URLencode` uses RFC1738 before R 3.2.1 (check https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html), but still encodes spaces as `%20`. Note that `http_build_query` also accepts an `enc_type` argument, which can be set to `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986` and which will encode spaces as `%20` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Comment: Thanks Joris, alas I have no control whatsoever over the PHP server. I cannot change the media type or the `enc_type`. I currently ignore the media type because I only get queries from that PHP server, so I know for sure all strings are _always_ RFC1738 encoded.