# Unable to delete S3 objects with spaces in name

Tags: amazon-s3

Through a typo I ended up creating a number of S3 files with spaces in their name. I realize based on the [key naming guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) that this is not an ideal situation, but the objects now exist. I have tried to delete them both from the AWS CLI and from the S3 console. Neither method produces an error, but the objects are not deleted. I tried renaming the files to remove the offending space, but this also fails on both CLI and console. How can I delete these objects?

Comment: Spaces are fine in object names. What error do you receive when trying to delete the object in the S3 Management Console? What is the error in the CLI?

Comment: Fails silently in both cases.

Comment: @SilencedTemporarily did you figure this out? I am actually using boto3 as Guy Wald suggests and ran into same issue.  When I list the objects in bucket, it replaces the spaces with '+' character. So "bucket name" becomes "bucket+name". Silently fails to delete when I pass that to delete_object(s) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using AWS SDKs (links to boto3 commands):

1. **List the objects** - See (boto3) [S3.Client.list_objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects)
2. **Filter the objects** (keys) you want to delete from the list
3. **Delete the objects** of the filtered list using [S3.Bucket.delete_objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.delete_objects)

Comment: I am actually using boto3 and ran into same thing.  When I list the objects in bucket, it replaces the spaces with '+' character. So "bucket name" becomes "bucket+name".  Silently fails to delete when I pass that to delete_object(s) method.

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to cases when you are using boto3 instead of aws cli but run into the same problem of the OP.

**The problem:**

When boto3 retrieves object names spaces in the key are encoded as "+" character.  I don't know why the spaces are not url-encoded as `%20` ([although this post has answers that might explain why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-should-space-be-encoded-to-plus-or-20)) Other special characters in the key name are url-encoded.  Ironically "+" in an object name is encoded as `%2B` by boto3.

**The solution:**

Before passing a key name to boto3 delete_objects method, I cleaned up the key this way:

```
remove_plus = x-www-form-urlencoded_key.replace("+", " ")
uncoded_key = urllib.parse.unquote(remove_plus)
response = client.delete_object(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Key=uncoded_key
)
```

I suppose there's a more correct way of handling application/x-www-form-urlencoded type strings, but this is working for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this command in your AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 rm s3://your-bucket-name/folderA/Family Name.txt
```

So there is a Space between "Family Name" object.

Then you can remove this object like:

```
aws s3 rm s3://your-bucket-name/folderA/Family" "Name.txt
```

**There should be one space between the double quotation marks.**