# Pass a literal %2B through onsubmit

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that replaces a space with a `+` sign. However, a literal `+` is passed as the parameter in the url and I need it to be convert to `%2B`. I tried in my JavaScript function to replace the space into `%2B` but it ends up converting it back to a plus sign in the URL.

```
function replacespace() { var p = document.getElementById('keywords') p.value = p.value.replace(/\s+/g, encodeURIComponent('+')); }
```

Any ideas on how to force the url to use `%2B` instead?

Comment: You should add your function to your question.

Comment: If you want a space on the server you would have to replace the `+` with `%20` and not `%2B`. You might also want to have a look at [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20)

Comment: Here's my function: `function replacespace() {
    var p = document.getElementById('keywords')
    p.value =  p.value.replace(/\s+/g, encodeURIComponent('+'));
  }`

Comment: I'm wanting to replace the space with a plus sign but an encoded value %2B, not a literal '+' in the url

Comment: Note that we generally like to have code in the question, not a comment. I've edited the code into your question this time. However, please [edit] your question now to provide an example of the HTML and the text you are attempting to use with this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```js
encodeURIComponent('+')
```

Comment: I tried using this but maybe I'm not using it correctly. When I use it in the url I'm still getting... keywords=BIOC+215 instead of keywords=BIOC%2B215