# Why does setting url.search and url.searchParams.set produce different values?

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode

For example if I have the code:

```
let c = new URL("http:/google.com");
c.search = "d d=m";
console.log(c.href)
```

It produces `"http://google.com/?d%20d=m"`

However, if I do:

```
let c = new URL("http:/google.com");
c.searchParams.set("d d", "m");
console.log(c.href)
```

This results in `"http://google.com/?d+d=m"`.

Why do these methods produce two different results?

Comment: They use different algorithms to produce the same result. `%20` is the space character URL encoded using "percent encoding". `+` is also the space character, encoded using the  "x-www-form-urlencoded" algorithm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20)