# UrlEncoded Serialization for whitespace

Tags: urlencode, flurl, x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm fairly new to deal with `x-www-form-urlencoded` message. However I encountered an different encoding with `PostUrlEncodedAsync` that I used in Flurl HTTP to encoded whitespace as `+`, yet if I used other urlencoding it would use `%20`

e.g item_name: Test Purchase

From Flurl: Test+Purchase

From other UrlEncoded: Test%20Purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either encoding should work, but historically `+` is and always has been the dominant implementation for `x-www-form-urlencoded`, so this is how Flurl does it. See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20).