# Why the change from %20 to + in generated campaign URL?

Tags: url

I've noticed my generated campaign URL has a "+" in place of what used to be "%20" with campaign names that have spaces. example URLs: (old)...campaign=Uchealth%20Today... (new) ...campaign=Uchealth+Today...
Why this change? Will it change how the URL operates ... or did I accidentally set a preference and didn't know? Thanks for the background and input. I have tried the link and it seems to work fine. But I want to make sure it's operating as it should on the back end before I send out a newsletter to my large list.

Comment: Please more details about your environment, how these URLs are generated, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to encode space to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20)