# Canonical URL with form values having spaces

Tags: html, seo

I'm taking form values in a URL Get method & form values may contain spaces.

I'm sending values (`key=555`) and (`drink='Red Bull'`) - note that there is a **space** between Red and Bull

The Chrome browser automatically makes the space as a + **plus sign** and the URL becomes:

`https://example.com/getformdata.php?key=555&drink=Red+Bull` - **URL1**

All good till here.
As per [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20) and [When should space be encoded to plus (+) or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-should-space-be-encoded-to-plus-or-20). These two thread say that plus sign is good for form queries, & %20 is good for URLs.

The situation is - I am also using the same URL (**URL1** - https://example.com/getformdata.php?key=555&drink=Red+Bull) as the `canonical URL` for that getformdata.php page for indexing in search engines.

**From SEO point of view**, should I replace the space with plus sign in the canonical URL? or should I replace space with %20?
i.e. should the canonical URL be `https://example.com/getformdata.php?key=555&drink=Red+Bull` or should it be `https://example.com/getformdata.php?key=555&drink=Red%20Bull` ?

Comment: I would recommend using the %20 encoding for spaces in URLs. This is because the %20 encoding is standard for representing URL spaces and is well supported by all major web browsers and search engines.