# How to determine if an nvarchar (or string) value is URLEncoded?

Tags: string, urlencode, urldecode, x-www-form-urlencoded

How could I safely determine whether or not to URLDecode an nvarchar value?

My specific case is that I have an nvarchar(max) field in a SQL Table containing 'message' text. Some entries appear to be URLEncoded (or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678602/4993856), which is similar but uses `+` for spaces) while others are regular text (ie. not encoded).

Is there a way to determine which entries would need to be URLDecoded?

The risk in URLDecoding everything, is text like:

> The $ is **+-10** times to ZAR which is between **%20** and **%21** cheaper. Call **+27**(0) 55 555 5555. **T+C** Apply.

would result in:

> The $ is  **-10** times to ZAR which is between   and **!** cheaper. Call  27(0) 55 555 5555. T C Apply.

*I suspect that a relatively safe option would be to assume that any values that contained spaces (' ') are **not** encoded (since URLEncoded or application/x-www-form-urlencoded would **not** contain spaces). Are there edge cases I might miss?*

Comment: The sent HTML message should have been URL encoded, and hence the received message URL decoded. And with the _same_ charset. Then `+` and `%20` are an irrelevant issue. Trying to patch a wrong encoding/decoding is not perfect as you demonstrate. To detect a wrong handling you could require the sending of some hidden input containg plus, space and such. Almost the same idea you got.

Comment: I believe only spaces and '&' are encoded.  If you see either of those in a string it is not encoded so should not be decoded.  Knowing it *is* URL-encoded doesn't seem possible, unless you guess that all strings will include at least one space.