# automatically URI decoding as needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, decode

```
a = 'some string'
b = URI.encode(a) # returns 'some%20string'
c = URI.encode(b) # returns 'some%2520string'
```

is there a way in ruby by which I can decode 'c' that gets me to 'a' string without decoding twice. My point is that I have some string that are encoded twice and some other that are encoded once. I want a method to automatically decode to normal string automatically identifying the number of time decoded.

Comment: you can try `URI.escape` and `URI.unescape` http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html

Comment: URI.unescape only unescapes once. I want to unescape as many time as it was encoded.

Comment: You can't determine this automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess the only way to achieve this is to keep decoding till it stop making changes. My facvourite for this kind of stuff is `do while` loop:

```
decoded = encoded
begin
  decoded = URI.decode(decoded) 
end while(decoded != URI.decode(decoded)  )
```

IMHO what you are looking for does not exist.

******** EDIT *************

Answers of another duplicate question for this on stackoverflow also suggests the same
[How to find out if string has already been URL encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295223/how-to-find-out-if-string-has-already-been-url-encoded)

Answer (score 2):

I can't find autodetection in docs, but its possible to implement this the following way with one extra `#decode` call:

```
def decode_uri(uri)
  current_uri, uri = uri, URI.decode(uri) until uri == current_uri
  uri
end
```

which will call `#decode` on `uri` until it will stop making any changes to it.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
def decode_uri(encoded)
  decoded = encoded
  begin
    decoded = URI.decode(decoded)
  end while(decoded != URI.decode(decoded))
  return decoded
end
```