# Rails check if URL is already encoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-encoding

I am using URI.encode to encode url's in my rail's application. But sometimes these url's can be already encoded and I do not want to encode them again. I can see one solution here: [How to find out if string has already been URL encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295223/how-to-find-out-if-string-has-already-been-url-encoded)

However, was wondering is there any API already available in ruby for doing this ?

Also as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295286/1475737 is decoding the string and checking its length with original a correct solution ?

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The `'uri'` module has a regular expression holding the list of characters which should be escaped for URI encoding:

```
require 'uri'

URI::REGEXP::UNSAFE

=> /[^-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]/n
```

So one solution is to test whether the given string matches this regexp and encode it only if does.

Comment: This does not seem to be defined for ruby 1.9.3 :(.

Comment: True. In fact, 'uri.encode' has been deprecated and the 'cgi' module should be used instead. Sadly, CGI does not provide a similar constant.

Comment: Also, This was suggested here as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/2295317/1475737 but its have a non-working example as well.

Comment: This has been rebuild in 1.9.3
You can try the following: ***URI::Parser.new.pattern*** but not sure if this returns what you want....