# URLEncoder.encode() have some problem with facebook in android

Tags: java, android

hi i am working on facebook app and when i am posting my message which is perfectly post but 
but space between two word which gives '+' sign sign.
eg::  Hello+Good+Morning.... so can any one tell me how to fix this please i am waiting.

```
public void postMessage() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{   
  String posttext = "";     
  posttext = editText.getText().toString().trim();      
  AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(oauth);
  Bundle params = new Bundle();     
  params.putString("access_token", access_token);
  params.putString("message", URLEncoder.encode(posttext,"UTF-8"));     
  mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", this);
}
```

---

Comment: see this post and choose easiest that suits your needs

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java/4605816#4605816

Answer (score 0):

Try putting %20 instead of space.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer and i put the %20 in place of <space> but it is still not work can any other solution....