# UrlEncodedFormEntity Replacement

Tags: java, android, connection, httpclient

We have web server which only accepts  decoded value from android phone

As example

"http://www.url.com/data/?name=hello World"

returns expected rssult

but when we are trying to use

"http://www.url.com/data/?name=URLEncoder.encode("hello World")"

gives nothing.

We can not change the web service.

But as we all know java only accept encoded url

How can we achieve  the goal so that we can send the decoded url as it is to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please restructure the question, to make it more clear? also the below statement appear to be incorrect (Assuming you are using Java)

> http://www.url.com/data/?name=URLEncoder.encode("hello World")

Comment: can you please let me know what will be the correct statement.

Comment: Checkout the Question and all the Answers form another Question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java