# why apache-commons lib encoding space as + not as %20?

Tags: java, apache-commons, url-encoding, apache-commons-codec

i'm using `URLCodec` from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec.html) to encode URL, but it encode space as `+` NOT as `%20`

why? and what is the solution?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20)

Of course, you can always do `url.replace("+", "%20");` if you need it (after encoding)

Comment: @Johan: I deleted my comment before seeing yours, because I felt like I was sniping at Bozho, and that wasn't my intent. w3schools isn't very reliable. For instance, to pick a random example, if you relied on their description of the JavaScript `String#replace` function (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), you wouldn't know that you can supply a function for the second parameter, which is *really useful*.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder anyway thanks for pointing the unreliability of w3schools. I removed the quote anyway, it is not that much relevant anyway.

Comment: *"Of course, you can always do `url.replace(" ", "%20");"`...* That would be a bad idea (you don't want to do this before encoding, you'll end up with an encoded `%`; and the space isn't there *after* encoding). You'd want `.encode(str).replace("+", "%20");`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yup, you are right, I meant after the encoding, but forgot that it's turned into a plus :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `+` is an equally valid way of encoding a space. What are you trying to "solve"?

Comment: dear, i need that .. where i have web service that understand %20 and not + .. check both of these plz http://www.aydeena.com/Services/Search.svc/JSON/SearchByText/deira+city+center      http://www.aydeena.com/Services/Search.svc/JSON/SearchByText/deira%20city%20center

Comment: @adham: In that case, that web service is not adhering to the standard. It should be fixed.

Comment: @adham: if your webservice can't decode a + as a space, it is broken and not the encoding. If the root cause, the non-conformant webservice, I would bet that some manual string processing is going on, and god forbid a regex, instead of using a decoding function designed to conform to the specification.

Comment: You're not supposed to decode + as a space in an URL for other than the query string

Answer (score 2):

The URLCodec encodes stuff suitable a submitted form, which is not the same as percent encoding a URL. There's more explanation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java) for how you should encode your URL.