# How to represent a string URL for special character?

Tags: java, string, url, special-characters

I am newbie to this and couldn't find exact answer. I have special characters in a URL such as,

```
"&", "#", "?" "<"
```

it causes a problems. (If someone can suggest how to deal with such situation then it would be an additional help). My main problem is that, how can I represent a string literal in JAVA for following kind of URL ?

```
"x###y"
```

I learned that we need to put its `hex` code value (using `%`). Can someone suggest that exact answer to fix this URL problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode(YOUR_STRING, "UTF-8");
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java) for a way to only encode the part of the url you need:

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to URL encode the address.

See :-

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: URLEncoder is for form encoding not for URL encoding. "...HTML form encoding...."  but the I agree that the naming is very bad and causes misunderstandings

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on where the data is in the URL. There will be different encoding rules for different parts of the URL.

*The exact form may also depend on what URI format the server is expecting.*

Parameters in the query part can usually be encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` using the [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8")
             + "="
             + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8")
             + "&"
             + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8")
             + "="
             + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");
```

If you need to encode in other parts of the URI (the path part, or the fragment part) read [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/12/java-safe-character-handling-and-url.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
URLEncoder is not for encoding URLs it is there to encode form data
```

see the following link for more details

[HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java/4605816#4605816)