# Convert String to HTML Ready text for MAILTO: URL

Tags: java, html, string, parsing

I am writing a large Java Application in which I would like to include a "Send Email" button. 
All it does is open a `mailto` url with the appropriate headers.

The only difficulty I am having is parsing the input strings so that they are formatted appropriately, for example:
`mailto:someone@somewhere.net?subject=This is the subject`
needs to become
`mailto:someone@somewhere.net?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject`

Comment: Hi,
Possibly duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html), specifically the `encode` method that can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: *The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".*

Comment: The answer is actually given in [the question that red eyes dev linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java), though it's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: That looks and sounds like exactly what I need, but according to eclipse, its depreciated. =/

Comment: There are two, you have to use the one that's `encode(String, String)`. Haven't tried but I think you should be able to pass one of [these](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) according to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to "URLEncode" (translates the space characters (' ') to %20.

See this document: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Like Michael Myers commented on my post, this converts them to "+" not "%20"