# Escape non english characters in a url

Tags: java, url, character-encoding, non-english

How can I escape non-english characters like "ö" from my url since it causes 404 response error. I am using Java. Please help me.

Comment: Url encoding? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E.g. by using URL-Encoding as specified in RFC3986 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). Please also have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Java provides some methods to do this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Be aware of different encodings like ISO-8859-1/15, UTF-8. Depending on this for example an 'ö' will be encoded to %F6 or &C3%D6 (or sth. like this).

Answer (score 3):

use URLEncoder/ URLDecoder in the java.net package

Answer (score 3):

Try the [java.net.URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, there was a 'ü' in URL path. After a few hours of experimenting with various SO posts I got this ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)):

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());

url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
```

Trick is in converting URI to URL. Most answers ended with URI.toURL() method call. While this method correctly encodes whitespaces and non-letter characters, it doesn't encode non-ASCII letters. Method URI.toASCIIString() is answer to that problem.

Comment: Great find! Thank you, works like a charm! (I had cyrillyc letters embedded in URL and URLEncoder.encode() wasn't able to encode them).