# Translating php code to jsp

Tags: php, jsp

```
$postdata = http_build_query(array('name' => $album_name,'message' => $album_description));
$opts = array('http' =>array( 'method'=> 'POST',
                              'header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                              'content' => $postdata));
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Could anyone tell me similar function on jsp

http_build_query() is php function, similar function in Jsp is what?

stream_context_create() also php function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [scriptlets](http://www.jsptut.com/Scriptlets.jsp) you can call java libraries in jsps.

For **http_build_query**, the analog in Java is the [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class. Here's [a simple tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java/2595894#2595894) on how to use it.

For **stream_context_create**, I guess you want to send an http request to a server, the analog in Java is [Java.net](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). See [this post for mini a torial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).