# Convert text to URL

Tags: java, url

Is there any way to transform a request like this:

```
"Annotation text="President Obama called Wednesday on Congress to extend a tax break
for students included in last year's economic stimulus package, arguing that the policy
provides more generous assistance."
confidence="0.2" support="20" 
sparql="SELECT DISTINCT ?x WHERE { ?x a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/OfficeHolder>; . 
?x ?related <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chicago>; }" 
policy="whitelist"
```

Into this?

http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate?text=President%20Obama%20called%20Wednesday%20on%20Congress%20to%20extend%20a%20tax%20break%20for%20students%20included%20in%20last%20year%27s%20economic%20stimulus%20package,%20arguing%20that%20the%20policy%20provides%20more%20generous%20assistance.&confidence=0.2&support=20&sparql=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fx%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fx+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FOfficeHolder%3E+.%0D%0A%3Fx+%3Frelated+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FChicago%3E+.%0D%0A%7D

I know that spaces are equal to %20 but I don't know the other conversions.
Is there any Java library that can do the conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
URLEncoder.encode(textAfterQuestionMark);
```

Comment: i want point this to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java too

Answer (score 0):

The single parameter version of encode is marked as deprecated. To be more assured of what the method will return, it's best to specify an encoding character set.

```
URLEncoder.encode( "foobar", "UTF-8" );
```

The different is that for the single parameter version, "the resulting string may vary depending on the platform's default encoding".