# Sending sms via java

Tags: java, sms

I am going to send sms via java. The problem is the sms gateway ask me to send in this format

```
http://push1.maccesssmspush.com/servlet/com.aclwireless.pushconnectivity.listen
ers.TextListener?userId=xxxxx&pass=xxxx&appid=xxxx&subappid=xxxx&msgtyp
e=1&contenttype=1&selfid=true&to=9810790590,9810549717&from=ACL&dlrre
q=true&text=This+is+a+test+msg+from+ACL&alert=
```

The problem how to call this from a java application is it possible or does it need special libraries? IS it using HttpURLConnection will do the job? Thank you.

A Sample code I have done below is this correct.

```
URL sendSms1 = new URL("http://push1.maccesssmspush.com/servlet/com.aclwireless.pushconnectivity.listen
    ers.TextListener?userId=xxxxx&pass=xxxx&appid=xxxx&subappid=xxxx&msgtyp
    e=1&contenttype=1&selfid=true&to=9810790590,9810549717&from=ACL&dlrre
    q=true&text=This+is+a+test+msg+from+ACL&alert=");

URLConnection smsConn1 =
    sendSms1.openConnection();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just an HTTP call, you don't need anything special in Java (or any modern language, I expect).  Just build up the string as appropriate*, then make an HTTP request to that URL.

Take a peek at the Sun tutorial [Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) if you need to pick up the basics of how to do the request part in Java.  This uses the built-in classes, I'm sure there are dozens of libraries that handles connections in funky and/or convenient ways too, so by all means use one of those if you're familiar with it.

*One potential gotcha which might not have occurred to you - your query string arguments will have to be URL-encoded.  So the `+` characters for example in the `text` parameter, are encoded spaces (which would have a different meaning in the URL).  Likewise, if you wanted to send a `?` character in one of your parameters, it would have to appear as `%3F`.  Have a look at the accepted answer to [HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java) for an example of how you might build the URL string safely.

Comment: @Doyle I have updated with some codes can you verify if that is some reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple GET request, you can use Apache HttpClient libarary for executing such a request. Have a look into a tutorial by Vogella here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html for sample source code and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use java.net.URL library。

like this

```
// at this before you need to generate the urlString as "http://push1.maccesssmspush.com/servlet/com.aclwireless.pushconnectivity.listen
ers.TextListener?userId=xxxxx&pass=xxxx&appid=xxxx&subappid=xxxx&msgtyp
e=1&contenttype=1&selfid=true&to=9810790590,9810549717&from=ACL&dlrre
q=true&text=This+is+a+test+msg+from+ACL&alert="

URL url = new URL(urlString);
// send sms
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();// open the url
// and you, also can get the feedback if you want
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
urlConnection.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: yes I need to get the delivery status how will the bufferedreader will be helpful here.As part of the url I need to send  dlrreq=true so that I get the delivery status.

Answer (score -2):

```
URL url = new URL("http://smscountry.com/SMSCwebservice.asp");
HttpURLConnection urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

**[Edit]**

```
urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
urlconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlenc‌​oded");     
urlconnection.setDoOutput(true); 

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(postData); 
out.close(); 

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlconnection.getInputStream()));

String decodedString; 

while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) { 
  retval += decodedString; 
}
```

Comment: how if I need to wait for some delivery status message after calling the openConnection is there any method for that?

Comment: I don't think so. it is just plain HTTP request which is asynchronous. You can read the output like this `urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  urlconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
  out.write(postData);
  out.close();
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(urlconnection.getInputStream()));
  String decodedString;
  while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
   retval += decodedString;
  }`

Comment: Please learn how to format code blocks, then edit that mess of code (in the comment) into the answer.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I guess you cannot add new line in comment

Comment: No, you can't, but the style of formatting you used for the code in the answer was wrong as well, the double ` simply makes the text show as fixed width font with gray BG.  Indenting lines by 4 chars produces a much better look.  Try re-editing the original text both ways and compare them side-by-side.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: you must consider valid points before voting down the answer

Comment: If I had not already voted it down, I would now since you seem to have ignored my advice.  You 'must' live and learn.

Comment: you can only vote down an answer if it is not useful and not if it is properly formatted

Comment: @all so which way should I proceed now to capture the delivery status?