# HttpURLConnection and encoded characters in the URL

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have a code like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://foo.com/?param=paj%E9");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
```

However, it seems like the openConnection is supressing the "%E9" part of the url, and the server ends up receiving a request http://foo.com?param=paj

Am I forgetting to apply any different setting for this to work properly?

Thanks!

EDIT: The url "http://foo.com/?param=paj%E9" is already encoded (from http://foo.com/?param=pajé), and this should be the request the server should receive. If I try to access http://foo.com/?param=paj%E9 straight from the browser, it works as expected. If I URLEncode "paj%E9", I'll be double-encoding the parameter, and the server would see "paj%E9" instead "pajé" upon decoding the value. 
I'm actually trying to build a proxy, and therefore I receive the urls already encoded. The problem is that whenever I pass such an encoded parameter to be requested using HttpURLConnection, it simply ignores the encoded part (like %E9).

Comment: you need to URL encode the request params.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use java.net.URI class to encode your URL instead of handle it on your own. Chek this:
[HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code
URLEncoder.encode("中文", "utf-8")