# Using BASE64 Encoder to encode a string containing raw characters

Tags: java, base64

The string that I want to send contains `#` because of this, in the server only the string upto `#` is recieved. How should I use BASE64Encoder in the client side to encode the String. PLease remember that I have a string which contains the `#`. And how to decode it in the server?

Comment: [BASE64 encoded charset](http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html) doesn't have the number sign (#) character. So, you can convert any string with # characters into BASE64 encoded version where the latter doesn't include any #. For example plain-text string `#123` will be `IzEyMw==` in BASE64 encoded form. Perform this on the client side. On the server side, it should decode the BASE64 encoded string back into its plain-text string version.

Comment: Base64 encodes an arbitrary sequence of bytes. Whatever your problem is, it's not in encoding the `#` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `URLEncoder` and `URLDecoder` classes for this purpose.

```
String urlParam = URLEncoder.encode(param);
```

....

```
String param = URLDecoder.decode(urlParam);
```

Comment: thanks, it works now. But what was the problem originally? And what does URLEncoder do?

Comment: Sorry for de-accepting your answer. See my question. I have edited it with the problem.

Comment: :I am Sorry your code works now suddenly. I don't know what the problem was but then the difference was visible. Now suddenly it is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are passing non-url-encoded arguments in query string. You don't need Base64 for it, just url-encode.

See [HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java):

```
URI uri = new URI( 
        "http",  
        "www.google.com",  
        "/ig/api", 
        "weather=São Paulo#123", 
        null); 
String request = uri.toASCIIString();
```

Comment: What should be the corresponding command in teh server to obtain the original string?