# Split "Subject" key word into Outlook subject line java

Tags: outlook

I have a problem using Outlook and I was hoping that I can receive some help. My application is sending an email with a hyperlink. When replying using this hyperlink, the subject should get automatically filled in, but here is the issue: the subject is empty because the hyperlink is faulted.

**Example:** mailto: dealapproval@system.com?subje ct=Proposal blablabla.. The special word "subject" is truncated and the hyperlink is faulted. For some users it is working fine and for others I'm facing this issue. I don't think the issue is with my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the URL correctly. Have a look on this question:
[HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)

Comment: v_approved_comment := 'To approve this ' || v_deal_or_prop_name2 || ': ' ||
                                '<a href=' || '"mailto:' ||
                                v_proposalapprovalemail || '?subject=' ||
                                adjust_text_for_html(v_subject_html) || '">' || 
                                v_proposalapprovalemail || '</a><br>';

Comment: and I have a java procedure called into my pl sql package

Comment: What language is the above construct actually?

Comment: But, if I perform a query from database, the "subject" appears correctly, so the application is not sending the word truncated...it gets truncated when trying to reply from Outlook. For the users that are using a specific domain is working fine...for the users that are using the second domain mail it gets faulted...could it be a server configuration issue?

Comment: I don't understand you problem correctly. Does the subject in your link is escaped? Are the whitspaces replaced with `%20` ?

Comment: Yes, into my code I am replacing the whitspaces with %20: v_subject_html := replace(v_subject, ' ', '%20');

Comment: The problem is that the word subject when I'm hovering the hyperlink received in the mail looks like this: mail to:mailto: dealapproval@system.com? subje ct=Proposal blablabla. and if clicking on it...the subject is empty because of this extra space in the midle of the word subject

Comment: I think there are some pieces missing to answer that. Where does your question link to Java? Where is your PLSql query fired? etc... Try to come up with some mor detailed information in your post.

Comment: The code for sending email, creating the subject etc are made in oracle, also in oracle, we have a java source for creating the mime message. The emails are send when a background job is running.