# URL encoding + sign

Tags: java, urlencode, url-encoding, urldecode

I have an application with `+` sign in its name (eg. `DB+JSP.jws`).

I get an error when trying to create connection as java encodes url `+` with spaces and hence cannot add the connection to `DB JSP/../META-INF/connection.xml` (File not found exception).

Any way to circumvent this only by using `URLEncoder.encode()` and `URLDecoder.decode()` methods?

Comment: see this it may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the URL correctly since '+' is a reserved character in a URL and can only be used in the correct context otherwise needs to be encoded with %2B.

Your URL string would encoded as "DB%2BJSP.jws".

So if you defined the following:

```
String url = URLEncoder.encode("DB+JSP.jws");
System.out.println(url);
```

The output would be the same:

```
DB%2BJSP.jws
```

You can prepend "http://localhost/" to the encoded URL as you need to.