# Java Passing URLConnection Parameter when query webpage

Tags: java

I would like to carry out searches on www.domain.com.au where a number of URL parameters need to be supplied in order to get a 
successful HTTP response. However, the

```
  1.  String url = "http://www.domain.com.au/"; // or www.realestate.com.au
  2.  String charset = "UTF-8";
  3.  String param1 = "Melbourne 3000 VIC"; // simple search on the web page
  4.
  5.  URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) new URL(url + "?" + param1).openConnection();
  6.  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
  7.  connection.connect();
  8.  connection.setDoInput(true);
  9.  connection.setDoOutput(false);
 10.  connection.connect();
      .......
```

The response was a HTTP 400 error. As a result, I need your advice on the following questions to understand where the issue is 
coming from:

( i ) Should the parameter name be param1, or something else on the web page? If so, what is it?

( ii ) Is line 5 correct assuming that the name of the parameter is param1? Is it necessary to include 
       URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset) even though line 6 has already set it explicitly.

The above code snippet works on other simple webpage where no parameters are required.

Your advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.net.URLConnection` is described very well in the following link by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: Thanks BalusC for offering your advice on this thread. I have read this article quite a number of times and use the example in it in this thread but it did not work for me, mostly likely due to my lack of knowledge & interpretation of what this article was referring to. It would be fantastic if you could lookup the same website to understand what the correct URL including parameter as well. Thanks, Jack

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1 . There you are not passing a name value pair. A typical GET URL request looks like

```
http://www.domain.com.au/?param1=value
```

you are just passing value and your URL looks like

`http://www.domain.com.au/?Melbourne 3000 VIC`

2 . Change line no. 5 to

`URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) new URL(url + "?parame1=" + param1).openConnection();`

Additionally encode the query string to substitute the spaces with html encode. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java) how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, suggestion 1. failed to even connect to www.domain.com.au & ended up at Google search prompting for clarification. On the other hand, the correct URsL should be something like the following that returned valid results:

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, suggestion 1. failed to even connect to www.domain.com.au & ended up at Google search prompting for clarification. On the other hand, the correct URsL should be something like the following that returned valid results:            

    http://www.domain.com.au/Search/buy/State/VIC/Area/Inner-City/Region/Melbourne-Region/Suburb/Melbourne/?ssubs=1&searchterm=Melbourne

Are you able to lookup this web page to clarify which valid URL including parameter should I use?

Thanks again,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the doamin.com.au website.

1) The name of the search parameter is "searchterm" and missed the key(key=value) in the URL.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url + "?searchterm=" + param1).openConnection();
```

2) You should include encoding if there are special characters.

Here are the code example which will return the content from the website:

```
    public void searchDomain(String key) throws Throwable
{
    String url = "http://www.domain.com.au/"; // or www.realestate.com.au
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String param1 = "Melbourne"; // simple search on the web page
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url + "?searchterm=" + param1).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.connect();

    java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    java.lang.StringBuffer sb = new java.lang.StringBuffer();
    java.lang.String str = br.readLine();
    while (str != null) 
    {
        sb.append(str);
        str = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
    connection.disconnect();

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```