# Encode an URL with Play 2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, urlencode

How can I encode an URL in a template with Play 2?

I search a helper like this:

```
<a href="@urlEncode(name)">urlEncode doesn't work now</a>
```

I have found a [pull request](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/294), but this doesn't seem to work with the actual play 2.0.3 release.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of 2.1 you can use `@helper.urlEncode`

```
<a href="@helper.urlEncode(foo)">my href is urlencoded</a>
```

Answer (score 14):

As I can see in [linked ticked](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/439-helper-for-url-encoding-in-template-missing#ticket-439-1) it will be resolved in Play 2.1

Quickest solution is placing ,method(s) for that in you controller (`Application.java` in this sample)

```java
public static String EncodeURL(String url) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException {
    url = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
    return url;
}

public static String EncodeURL(Call call) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return EncodeURL(call.toString());
}
```

and then using it in the view as required at the moment:

```html
<a href='@Application.EncodeURL(routes.Application.someAction())'>
    Encoded url form router</a>  <br/>

<a href='@Application.EncodeURL("/this/is/url/to/encode")'>
     Encoded url from string</a>  <br/>

<a href='@routes.Application.someAction()?encoded=@Application.EncodeURL(routes.Application.someOtherAction())'>
     Url mixed normal+encoded</a>  <br/>
```

Comment: java.net.URLEncoder is a very bad name since it should only be used to encode Query Paramters. But the general idea of how this can be implemented in play seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

Using @helper.urlEncode as in

`@helper.urlEncode("http://www.giulio.ro/image/magictoolbox_cache/3bf842518f40ca6b8a10b619b8e02daf/6/2/621/thumb320x320/0804-427 - 255 lei.jpg")`

returned

`http%3A%2F%2Fwww.giulio.ro%2Fimage%2Fmagictoolbox_cache%2F3bf842518f40ca6b8a10b619b8e02daf%2F6%2F2%2F621%2Fthumb320x320%2F0804-427+-+255+lei.jpg`

while what I needed/expected was

`http://www.giulio.ro/image/magictoolbox_cache/3bf842518f40ca6b8a10b619b8e02daf/6/2/621/thumb320x320/0804-427%20-%20255%20lei.jpg`

I used @scott-izu this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9542781/99248