# Slugging algorithm or library code in scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is there a good slugging algorithm or library out there to take a String of possibly all sorts of punctuation etc and convert it into a nice clean slug for a URL? Even better if the Play Framework has one already ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226508/encode-an-url-with-play-2?

Comment: thanks, not quite the same thing really, that is encoding all special chars as %... what I need is something to just create a human readable slug out of some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the method from Play 1 and copied it to a module:

https://github.com/mariussoutier/Play-Extensions/blob/master/app/Implicits.scala#L12