# Jsoup - how to deal with URLs that have space

Tags: google-app-engine, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to connect to a URL with a space in it but keep getting a URI syntax error.  Any ideas on how deal with this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should percent-encode URLs.  Space is represented as %20.

Additionally, some characters/symbols are used as delimiters in URLs (&, ?, =, etc.) and thus they cannot be put in the URL unless they are meant as delimiters.  For example, if you wanted to pass the string "1 &1" I would have to encode it as "1%20%261" or else it will not parse properly.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding for more details.

Answer (score 0):

URLs cannot have spaces, by RFC1738 (section 2.2):  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

For some additional background on how to handle this, see:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

In particular, one mechanism for encoding URLs can be found at:
[HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)