# Java URL Encode how to encode Hello World as Hello%20World

Tags: java, iis

Hi Um quite  new to Java and I want to encode Hello World it to Hello%20World . But when I use URLEncoder.encode it will encode the string as Hello+World and when we try to pass it via a Request to IIS it ll consider as a threat. How to encode as i mentioned ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4605816/680925.

Comment: I doubt that this is really the reason that IIS considers it to be a threat, as you say.

Comment: http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/60/404-Error-in-IIS-7-when-using-a-Url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path I got to know the IIS risk from there

Comment: URLEncoder is ok. Replacing + by %20 is a specific behaviour, java.lang.String.replace works perfectly for that.

Answer (score -1):

This only works for real URLs

```
URL u = new URL("Hello World");
String path = u.getPath();
```