# Encode URL using java and substitute %20 or other special characters

Tags: java, url, encoding, web

I want encode an URL in a way that special characters like " " (space) are substituted in the correct way (%20 in the case of spaces). No one of the solution I found online is working as expected.

I tryed using apache commons:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String bla="http://www.bla.com/bla.php?par1=bla bla bla";

        System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(bla));

    }
}
```

But it returns:

```
http://www.bla.com/bla.php?par1=bla bla bla
```

I tryed with java.net.URL:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        String bla="http://www.bla.com/bla.php?par1=bla bla bla";

        URL url = new URL(bla);


        System.out.println(url);

    }

}
```

But it returns:

```
http://www.bla.com/bla.php?par1=bla bla bla
```

I would expect:

```
http://www.bla.com/bla.php?par1=bla%20bla%20bla
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: have you tried URLEncoder?

Comment: Yes. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Try splitting into a `URI` with the aid of the `URL` class:

```
String sUrl = "http://bla.com:8080/test and test/bla.php?query=bla and bla";
URL url = new URL(sUrl);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
String canonical = uri.toString();

System.out.println(canonical);
```

Output:

```
http://bla.com:8080/test%20and%20test/bla.php?query=bla%20and%20bla
```

Comment: This could potentially cause double encoding if anything in sUrl was already percent encoded. Any ways to solve this?