# How can I encode special character by URI correctly?

Tags: java, http, url, uri, httpurlconnection

I have created an URL to get the file on the server.

However, the file name may contains special characters like: `~!@#$%^&*()` or
some Asian characters like Japanese, Chinese and Korean.

I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java/724764#724764) and adopt the solution:

```
String dwnStr= new String("http://") + `HOST_IP_ADDRESS` + new String('/')
                    + "picture/dog.jpg";
URL url= new URL(dwnStr);
URI uri= new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef()); // According to the official doc, it's in all cases.
url= uri.toURL();
(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

And it gets well in the condition that if the `dwnStr` doesn't contain any special character.By contrast,if the `dwnStr` contains `#` hash mark, the `URL` constructor would drop the words after `#`, taking it as fragment identifier.

Thus, I tried another solution (still in the above link. This time, I avoid to use `URL`:

```
uri = new URI("http", null, HOST_IP_ADDRESS, 80, null,URLEncoder.encode("picture/dog.jpg", "UTF-8"), null);
```

It even can't work for the file name which doesn't contain any special characters.

**What's the mistake I have made?**

**What strategy I can still adopt with?**

ps: 1. I have tried the chosen solution in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java/724764#724764) too. Of course, it doesn't work.

2. official doc link: [official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#quote)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `toASCIIString()` method. It returns a `String` that you can send to the remote server.

Another option is to use the `IDN` class's static method `toASCII`.