# How to fetch an URL containing non-ASCII characters (ą, ś ...) with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to parse some polish sites, but I have problem with special characters like "ą", "ś" in URL(!), for example `example.com/kąt` is readed like `example.com/k`

every query without this special characters works perfectly

I have tried `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", url)` but it does not work.

any other tips?

Comment: Can you provide us the site URL?

Comment: of course, http://sjp.pl/maść

Comment: Seems to already be solved since it works fine for me `System.out.println(Jsoup.connect("http://sjp.pl/maść").get());` (or maybe my polish locale helped somehow).

Comment: @Pshemo The url need to be encoded. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34928309/363573

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You want to encode your URL **before** passing it to Jsoup.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String url = "http://sjp.pl/maść";       
System.out.println("BEFORE " + url);

String encodedURL = URI.create(url).toASCIIString();
System.out.println("AFTER " + encodedURL);

System.out.println("Title: " + Jsoup.connect(encodedURL).get().title());
```

#### OUTPUT

```
 BEFORE http://sjp.pl/maść
 AFTER http://sjp.pl/ma%C5%9B%C4%87
 Title: maść - Słownik SJP
```

**French locale**
**Jsoup 1.8.3**