# Jsoup encoded URL with Umlaut

Tags: java, encoding, web-scraping, jsoup, non-ascii-characters

I'm having problem with scraping a URL with 'ö', so I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580318/how-to-fetch-an-url-containing-non-ascii-characters-%C4%85-%C5%9B-with-jsoup/34928309#34928309) (implemented below)

```
String url = "https://www.ariva.de/deutsche_börse-aktie/bilanz-guv?page=0";
    String encodedURL = URI.create(url).toASCIIString();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(encodedURL).get();
```

However, I still get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://www.ariva.de/deutsche_b%2525C3%2525B6rse-aktie/bilanz-guv?page=0
```

Comment: `%2525` indicates that you have 3 rounds of encoding, here.

Comment: even if i'm encoding the URL manually I get an Error though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jsoup.connect(url)` automatically encodes the provided URL, just place your url String directly there.