# Invalid characters at path

Tags: java, android, json, web

In my Android app, which fetches JSON data from an URL, I have to encode the username and password.
If I encode my username and use it in my URL, it throws an Invalid characters at path error.
However if I try the URL with the encoded username, it works!
I tried to URLEncode the URL and the username part itself, that gives me an internal server error.

not encoded String username: lc118820,
Base64 encoded String username: bGMxMTg4MjA=

```
            // Encrypting username and password
    username = Base64.encodeToString(username.getBytes(), 0);
    byte[] byteArray = DigestUtils.sha1(password);
    password = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    password = new String(Hex.encodeHex(password.getBytes()));

    getleerlingidurl = "http://somtoday.nl/" + schoolname + "/services/mobile/v10/Login/CheckMultiLoginB64/" + username + "/" + password + "/" + brin;
```

---

:EDIT:
I found a solution!
I changed username = Base64.encodeToString(username.getBytes(), 0); to Base64.encodeToString(username.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

Comment: So, in order to get some answers post the code you tried, meaning the request to the server, including the json part.

Comment: `=` is a reserved character in an URL (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Comment: I get it. But how do I use it in my app?

Comment: To get you app to use the reserved `=` have a look at URL encoding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java

Comment: @SeanF I know that, I tried it already