# Jersey 1.19 Grizzly 2.3.25 and Umlaute in URL - JUnit tests does not work while browser access does

Tags: url, jersey, grizzly

In a RESTFul Jersey solution I am trying to receive URLs that contain German Umlaut characters e.g.

```
http://localhost:8085/hello/hello/echo/ÄÖÜßööü
```

When I enter such URLs with a browser I get correct results.
When I test things with a JUnit test it doesn't work.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[ÄÖÜßäöü]> but was:<[ÃÃÃÃÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.bitplan.rest.test.TestHello.testUmlaute(TestHello.java:43)
```

the debug output is:

```
http://localhost:8085/hello/hello/echo/%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C%C3%9F%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC
http://localhost:8085/hello/hello/echo/ÄÖÜßäöü
GET:hello/echo/ÃÃÃÃÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼
```

and so it seems the url is not handled correctly by Grizzly/Jersey.

**How can I fix this or work around it?**

I found: https://github.com/javaee/grizzly/issues/1377  and tried different encodings e.g. as proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9542781/1497139 but that didn't make any difference.

I also set

```
server.getServerConfiguration().setDefaultQueryEncoding(Charsets.UTF8_CHARSET);
```

as outlined in https://github.com/javaee/grizzly/issues/1450 but still no luck

**JUnit Test** 
see https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplerest/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bitplan/rest/test/TestHello.java#L42

```java
@Test
public void testUmlaute() throws Exception {
 super.startServer();
 URI uri=new URI("http://localhost:8085/hello/hello/echo/ÄÖÜßäöü");
 System.out.println(uri.toASCIIString());
 System.out.println(uri.toString());
 WebResource wrs = Client.create().resource(uri);
 String result= wrs.accept("text/html; charset=utf-8").get(String.class);
 assertEquals("ÄÖÜßäöü",result);
}
```

**"Hello/Echo" Resource**

```java
package com.bitplan.hello.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("/hello")
/**
 * Simple Hello Resource
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class HelloResource {

  @Context
  UriInfo uriInfo;

  @Context
  Request request;

  @GET
  public String getHello() {
    return "Hello";
  }

  @GET
  @Produces("text/html")
  @Path("echo/{value}")
  public String getEcho(@PathParam("value") String value) {
    System.out.println(request.getMethod()+":"+uriInfo.getPath());
    return value;
  }
}
```

**maven dependencies**

```xml
    <properties>
      <!-- jersey version -->
      <!-- <jersey.version>2.22.2</jersey.version> -->
      <jersey.version>1.19.1</jersey.version> 
      <!-- http://grizzly.java.net/ -->
      <grizzly.version>2.3.25</grizzly.version>
     ...
    </properties>
  ...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Grizzly server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
    <version>${grizzly.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${grizzly.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http</artifactId>
    <version>${grizzly.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you say it works from browser with the same server, doesn't it mean that the problem might be on the client side?

Comment: Probably so. But the server should be able to  handle both the encode and non encoded versions of the url.

Comment: Could you pls. share complete testcase, so we can reproduce?

Comment: what are you missing?

Comment: It would be great to have a project on github, check it out and run/test

Comment: see3 https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplerest and https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplerest-api

Comment: The tests work fine for me, no error. From your report I see that there is some problem with encoding, but not sure where exactly, if it's on the client or server side. Are you able to take an HTTP packets dump using Wireshark or tcpdump to see what is getting sent over the wires?