# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 75

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to send GET request from java through Apache REST client and encountered this issue.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 75:
>   http://torrento.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Shared
>   Documents/test')/files    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
>     at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)    at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)  at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)  at
>   java.net.URI.(URI.java:588)     at
>   org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.(URIBuilder.java:82)    at
>   com.mstack.samples.sharepoint.SharepointApp.getAllFiles(SharepointApp.java:61)
>     at
>   com.mstack.samples.sharepoint.SharepointApp.main(SharepointApp.java:45)

Code snippet :-

```
            httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(requestUrl);
            System.out.println(uriBuilder);
            httpGet = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.build());
            httpGet.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + TOKEN);
            httpGet.addHeader("accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Where requestUrl is **`http://torrento.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/test')/files`**

I know the space between Shared and Documents is the issue. Tried to encode it. But that too didn't work. Please help

Comment: is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/724764/5655414 not what you want?

Comment: I've changed accordingly and ran into another issues. Can you say how should I change the code to get this working ?

Comment: *"Tried to encode it. But that too didn't work."* - Show us what you tried and what happened.  Because the solution is to encode the `path` part of the URL ... the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've obtained the solution by simply adding `requestUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");` 
But in case of other special characters this alone won't work. So we must encode url before sending request.

Cheers :)