# Replacing one character in string with another string excluding pattern

Tags: java, string, replace

I need to replace all '%' characters in string with "%25" but I don't want to replace % in %25 to avoid situation, when I get something like this %%25.
I want to do it in Java.
Example:
input: % sdfsdaf %25
expected result: %25 sdfsdaf %25

Do you know what should I use to get it?

Comment: What have you tried(?: so far)?\?

Comment: See [HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In order to ask propery questions you need to show what you have done and what errors you have found. Check the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know how to provide a mcve

Comment: use `replaceAll` with proper regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without discussing much and digging deep into what you are really trying to accomplish with the replacement ... the answer to your question could be something like :

```
myString.replaceAll("%(?!25)", "%25");
```

From [Pattern Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) ; The (?!...) part means "only match if the text following (hence: lookahead) this doesn't (hence: negative) match this. But it doesn't actually consume the characters it matches (hence: zero-width).

Section 3.5 of the [Link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) clarifies it in a bit more detail.