# Illegal character in path at index 65 exception [ java ]

Tags: java, regex, url, exception, web-crawler

I am trying to fetch a page using HTTPGET apache method but it throws me this exception :

```
Illegal character in path at index 65: http://doctorat.tuiasi.ro/Htm/Proiecte_POSDRU_17.02.2013/Proiecte europene.html
```

I know the space out there may be the cause of the problem but I am trying to filter the url like that

```
String url=everyUrl.getUrl().replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                if (url.contains("http://")) {
                    Pattern allowedUrlCharacters = Pattern
                            .compile("([A-Za-z0-9_.~:/?\\#\\[\\]@!$&'()*+,;" + "=-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+");
                    Matcher matcher = allowedUrlCharacters.matcher(url);
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        pushInFrontQueues(url);
                    }
                    // System.out.println(this.frontQueues.get(0).size());

                }
            }
```

What I am doing wrong ? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What's the full stack trace?  On which line in the code does the exception occur?

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in urls. You have one in "Proiecte europene.html"

Comment: @RiaanNel That's full stack trace

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java

Comment: @litelite I know , but I have tested id and should not pass the test  , but it does

Comment: What line does the error occur on?  That trace doesn't show a line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, your regex is finding a valid string. In fact, it's finding two valid strings. Take a look at [this](http://regexr.com/3fvsu) to see what I mean. It has found two matching groups.

You need to make sure to only match if the entire string matches. You can do that by surround your regex with `^` and `$`, like so:

```
"^([A-Za-z0-9_.~:/?\\#\\[\\]@!$&'()*+,;" + "=-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+$"
```

However, this pattern will likely match things you don't want such as `something%2else`. To only allow valid percent encoding, you might want something like this:

```
"^(%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|[^%][A-Fa-f0-9]|[G-Zg-z_.~:/?\\#\\[\\]@!$&'()*+,;=-])+$"
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I didn't just try to fix the regex. I updated the answer.

Comment: Added an even better regex to the answer.