# Twitter RestAPI call from java using space and OR

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-rest-api

In this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search), it has been explained how to use the Twitter search API, for example: 
Your search URL is:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=superman OR spiderman&result_type=recent`

when I do a GET call using the link from POSTMAN (setting OAuth 1 params)it works fine, but when i do the same GET call from JAVA, it gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 57: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=superman OR spiderman&result_type=recent
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
```

it works fine if i just search with one word without space and OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to encode the URL properly. For instance a space character must be replaced with %20. Here is a [table](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php) of encodings. Really, you should use a built in function. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java).