# Symbols and special characters in maps as keys THROUGH YML FILE

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, key, special-characters

Is it possible to store characters such as `:` `;` `/` `,` `.` in the keys in map in Java **that's mapped through application.yml**?

I'm trying to store URIs and a value associated with them through a mapping in application.yml file however since it's a key, it doesnt save any of the special characters

http://localhost:8080 becomes httplocalhost8080

Is there any way to preserve those lost characters?

**~~EDIT~~** 
I've tried escape characters, double, and single quotes around the keys and still once they are in the hashmap, they are ignored.

The property in the yml file has this structure:

```
  uri-example-config:
    keyToValueMap:
      http://localhost:8080 : String1
      http://exmaple.com: String2
      http://moreURIs.com: String2
```

And then my config is:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "uri-example-config")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class URIProperties {
    private Map<String, String> keyToValueMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

**~~~~EDIT 2~~~~**

Yes, i can easily map.put("http://localhost:8080"...) and the strings is preserved as expected. ***Doing it through yml file*** with config and properties causes this issue.

Comment: So you are trying to have `http://localhost:8080` as a key in yaml map? Have you tried escaping the sequence using " or ` signs?

Comment: @michalk yeah, did not change anything. Posted a sample code above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Java HashMap accept any Object (String is an Object) as key !**
Also, HashMap will not write/change your String.

I think your problem comes from the loading of your .yml

Yaml accept special characters as key if its in double quote.

```
- "http://localhost:8080"
```

Check your serializer / deserializer

**Edit**
There is an explanation on the [github of the project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13404#issuecomment-395307439)

You should surround your string with brackets

```
- '[http://localhost:8080]'
```

Comment: Posted my example above, not sure if serializer comes into play here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create an [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) like this:

```
URI uri = new URI("http", null, "localhost", "8080", "/my/api");
String uriAsString = uri.toASCIIString();
```

And then set it into your map as a string.

I suggest you to look at this post, you might find a solution there:
[HTTP URL Address Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is**

For your example in java you just have to escape it right.

```
    Map testmap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
    Object testObject="a value Object";
    testmap.put("http://localhost:8080",testObject);
    for (Object s:testmap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Will print out:

> http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use characters like  `: ; / , .` in a `String` key `Map`, if the key is of type `String` so the Map can accept any string with any character.

The key should be of type a class that implements `equals` and `hashCode` methods. If these methods aren't available so they will be inherited from the `Object` class.