# image url is not compliant with RFC2396

Tags: html, facebook

I have problem with image url within facebook's meta tag:

```
<meta property='og:image' content="images/defaultRFCa.jpg"/>
```

Facebook's Linter (debugger) screams:

```
The image url obrazky/defaultRFCa.jpg is not compliant with RFC2396 and will not be displayed correctly.
```

I've tried absolute and relative url's but with no effect. I've tried [this stackoverflow advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304806/encode-and-decode-rfc2396-urls) too.
 Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use absolute, not relative path

```
<meta property='og:image' content="http://yourdomain.com/images/defaultRFCa.jpg"/>
```

btw you forgot you Czech "obrazky/" from your linter output

Comment: Yes, I translated it, but not completely. And I wrote that I have tried absolute url with no effect.

Comment: @culter: Give me absolute link to that image. You'll see you're wrong

Comment: Just as I said, I've tried it. my relative link was http://www.mydomain.com/obrazky/defaultRFCa.jpg. When I entered it to browser, it displays that image. Is it still wrong?

Comment: I've checked FB code line after line and I found that the app_id was wrong. When I correct it, it didn't display that error no more. But I don't know why Linter displays that url is wron instead of app_id. I hope that google+ will replace this FB s...